# How do I increase the size of logcat buffers?

Tags: usb-debugging, logging, developer-options

How do I increase the size of `/dev/log/main` by a factor of 10? My understanding is the log has a fixed size (16K?) and rolls over when that limit is reached. I'd like to find out what the log size is currently set at and increase it by a lot.

I'm debugging an issue that occurs infrequently when the device hasn't been used for a long period of time (maybe an hour?). I've instrumented the code with log messages so I can understand what is happening when the bug occurs.

My problem is my instrumentation causes the log to roll over in about 2 minutes. I would like to increase the size of `dev/log/main` by a factor of 10 if possible.

Comment: I presume that leaving it connected to the computer with `adb logcat > my_log_file.log` running isn't an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out the actual size of the ring buffer, you can use

```
$ adb logcat -g
```

To adjust the size of the ring buffer, you might try

```
$ adb logcat -r <kbytes>
```

At least that's what some tutorials say. For more details, you might want to read ["adb logcat" Command Options and Log Buffers](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Command-Option-Log-Buffer.html).

P.S.: I guess those settings (manual adjusted ring buffer size) will not survive a reboot -- just to consider.

Comment: actually it needs tp be  adb logcat -r 100000 -f sdcard/log.log . -f is required.

Comment: I dont think -r is useful as from reading the logcat manual, it will set the size at which the logcat tool will rotate the file it is writing out to using the "-f" option and **NOT** the size of the in-memory ring buffer used by the logger kernel module!

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Android 5, the in-kernel *logger* driver is [deprecated](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/c611e8535564e05f981c500989009d5f272ce46e) which exposed the ring buffers through `/dev/log/*` character devices. Instead a userspace logging daemon named **logd** manages buffers “main”, “system”, “radio”, “events”, and “crash”. Optional buffers “security” (e.g. for `adb shell`/`push`/`pull` logging) and on `userdebug` builds “kernel” (for `klogd`) and “stats” (for logs statistics) were added later. `logd` mainly covers the functionality of its desktop counterpart [syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd), but also includes [klogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/klogd) and partially [auditd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.auditd) to get logs from SELinux subsystem of kernel. Behavior of logging daemon is controlled through different [properties](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/logd/README.property).

Apps and native processes write their logs to relevant buffers through socket `/dev/socket/logdw` (by making use of [liblog](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#logging) functions). `logcat` command reads the buffers from `/dev/socket/logdr` while controls the daemon and buffers through `/dev/socket/logd` socket. Use `-g`/`-G` options to get and set size of individual buffers:

```
  -g, --buffer-size
                  Get the size of the ring buffer.
  -G <size>, --buffer-size=<size>
                  Set size of log ring buffer, may suffix with K or M.
```

There's also an option in Developer Options: ***Logger buffer sizes*** (which also sets property `persist.logd.size`) to set same size for all buffers.

`persist.logd.size` is read from `/data/property/` which isn't available unless `/data` is mounted and decrypted (in case of FDE). But sometimes buffers may overflow even before that, so the solution is to set `ro.logd.size` (through `default.prop`/`build.prop` or directly in some `*.rc` file) before the `logd` service is started.

Comment: Thank you very much for that tip about increasing the size of the buffer persistently between boots! It was very useful while debugging a timing error that occurred before I could adjust the size.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to change the default size for a log buffer, to persist between reboots, you can recompile the kernel with updated buffer sizes.

The file containing log buffer definitions is:

```
<kernel>/drivers/staging/android/logger.c
```

The versions I'm looking at use a macro to define log buffers in that file:

```
DEFINE_LOGGER_DEVICE(variable, name, size)
```

There will likely be a number of loggers; "main" is usually the one you're looking for.

Comment: This should be known on all the related questions here and on stackoverflow ! Nice find. Of note, Main and System are the default logcat buffers. You'd probably want to increase them both. Well, depending on if your Android version uses them. See logcat -g and logcat -h