# logcat log loss

Tags: logging

I am using android jellybeans. There is a large amount of debug information being dumped by many components. So, I notice that logs from my application are often lost. I have tried dumping logcat log in to a file in the phone and then doing a "adb pull". Still, there is a good amount of logs thar are lost. Is there a way to ensure no logs are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Logging on Android uses a ring buffer with a fixed size (exact size depends on different criteria), see e.g. [What is the size limit for Logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat), so older entries get overwritten once the buffer is "full". You can adjust the size of the buffer (see: [How do I increase the log size of dev/log/main?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17572/16575)) -- but those adjustments would probably not survive a boot.

If you really want to make sure no log data is lost, you would need to pipe the log to some "external ressource" -- either to some "external storage" or "the cloud".

Answer (score 0):

First the log in android it's a circular log, that means that if you have a lot of logging going out there you're older statements will be overwritten. Why don't you use a custom solution like microlog for android http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/

You can use command logcat | grep 'YOURTAG', for only showing your apps logs. It can be done through any Terminal Emulator, or using Android Debug Bridge (adb)