# Enabling logcat on boot

Tags: adb, logging

I'm trying to debug a ROM problem, that cause Android animation boot run forever, occuring after the first reboot.

Trying to read the log with logcat ,executing from shell `adb logcat -d` before powering on the phone, but adb remains in `< waiting for device >` state

Before rebooting Android, I test adb logcat and it was working fine.

Anyone can help? How to read boot logs?

Comment: Logcat is part of the OS, hence it can not run before the OS boot process has at least started up to the point where logcat is loaded.

Comment: I found some log files in /cache partition, but they are completely empty

Comment: You can persist the logcat: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216659/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216857/218526. Or persist the kernel log: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213460/218526